# is there a function for a string like istream::putback in C++?

Tags: c++, string, function, istream

I know that an istream::putback function lets us put the last character we got from an input stream back into the input stream.

is there a similar function for a string?

if not how do I put the last character I got from an input string back to the input string?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `operator+=`

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Strings aren't streams. The last character you got from a string _is still there_. Go into more detail about your problem, ideally with a [mcve].